# Laravel 5 : DB query with Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is it possible to do the same query with Eloquent in order to have Object in return ?

Here is the code :

```
$activity = Activity::find($id);

$users = $activity->users;

$photos_by_users = [];

foreach ($users as $key => $user) {

        $photos_by_user = DB::table('photos')
        ->join('steps', 'steps.id', '=', 'photos.step_id')
        ->join('activities', 'activities.id', '=', 'steps.activity_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'activities.user_id')
        ->select('photos.*', 'activities.id as activity_id', 'activities.user_id', 'users.name')
        ->where('activity_id', '=', $id)
        ->where('activities.user_id', '=', $user->id)
        ->get();

        array_push($photos_by_users, $photos_by_user);

}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change line

```
$photos_by_user = DB::table('photos')
```

into

```
$photos_by_user = Photo::query()
```

and it should work.